# If Formula to populate Website between 1 of 2 fields

Tags: workflow, formula, if

Trying to populate the Website field on the Account if it's blank. Using an IF formula within a workflow to populate when ISBLANK(Website).

The WFR is working for the first field, which is Core Domain, but not if both Core Domain and Website is working. It should pull from LS Company Website...

```
IF(
ISBLANK(Website),
Core_Domain__c,
IF(
ISBLANK(Core_Domain__c),
LS_Company_Website__c,
NULL
)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a BLANKVALUE formula:

```
BLANKVALUE(Website, BLANKVALUE(Core_Domain__c, LS_Company_Website__c));
```

It's often not required to use the IF statement, and this is one of those circumstances.

Comment: For some reason that doesn't seem to be working either Core Domain or LS Company Website. The previous formula worked for Core Domain.

For the workflow rule itself I'm using "Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria" and the Criteria is Website [Equal] null

Comment: @goldk How is it "not working?" What value are you getting? What are you expecting? It's kind of hard to work with a "not working" error.

Comment: There isn't an error. When I populate the Core Domain field (and Website is blank) and save the record it's not populating the website field. I run the same process and populate LS Company Website (and make sure both Core Domain and Website are blank) and save the record and still Website is not being populated.

Comment: @goldk It should be. Have you activated the workflow rule? Did you check the entry criteria? Have you tried creating a debug log? Did you activate the rule? Can we see the criteria for the rule?

Comment: Yes on activate. Yes on entry criteria, I changed it multiple times to be formula vs. format and edited evaluation criteria. Added image of Rule criteria to original post

Can you help with the debug log? How do I create that?

Comment: @goldk can we see the criteria for the workflow rule? I suspect the problem is there.

Comment: Yup - added that to original message.

Comment: Figured it out!!!! Your formula worked. There was another WFR that was populating the Core domain field, so it was never blank...